# Bash format uptime to show days, hours, minutes

Tags: linux, bash, uptime

I'm using uptime in bash in order to get the current runtime of the machine. I need to grab the time and display a format like 2 days, 12 hours, 23 minutes.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34017/convert-linux-sysuptime-to-well-format-date

Comment: With a recent procps, you can use `uptime -p`. This appeared somewhere between 3.3.4 and 3.3.9.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

My `uptime` produces output that looks like:

```
$ uptime
 12:49:10 up 25 days, 21:30, 28 users,  load average: 0.50, 0.66, 0.52
```

To convert that to your format:

```
$ uptime | awk -F'( |,|:)+' '{print $6,$7",",$8,"hours,",$9,"minutes."}'
25 days, 21 hours, 34 minutes.
```

#### How it works

- `-F'( |,|:)+'`

  awk divides its input up into fields.  This tells awk to use any combination of one or more of space, comma, or colon as the field separator.
- `print $6,$7",",$8,"hours,",$9,"minutes."`

  This tells awk to print the sixth field and seventh fields (separated by a space) followed by a comma, the 8th field, the string `hours,` the ninth field, and, lastly, the string `minutes.`.

### Handling computers with short uptimes using sed

Starting from a reboot, my `uptime` produces output like:

```
 03:14:20 up 1 min,  2 users,  load average: 2.28, 1.29, 0.50
 04:12:29 up 59 min,  5 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.08, 0.48
 05:14:09 up  2:01,  5 users,  load average: 0.13, 0.10, 0.45
 03:13:19 up 1 day, 0 min,  8 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.04, 0.05
 04:13:19 up 1 day,  1:00,  8 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.05, 0.21
 12:49:10 up 25 days, 21:30, 28 users,  load average: 0.50, 0.66, 0.52
```

The following `sed` command handles these formats:

```
uptime | sed -E 's/^[^,]*up *//; s/, *[[:digit:]]* users.*//; s/min/minutes/; s/([[:digit:]]+):0?([[:digit:]]+)/\1 hours, \2 minutes/'
```

With the above times, this produces:

```
1 minutes
59 minutes
2 hours, 1 minutes
1 day, 0 minutes
1 day,  1 hours, 0 minutes
25 days, 21 hours, 30 minutes
```

#### How it works

- `-E` turns on extended regular expression syntax.  (On older GNU seds, use `-r` in place of `-E`)
- `s/^[^,]*up *//`

  This substitutes command removes all text up to `up`.
- `s/, *[[:digit:]]* users.*//`

  This substitute command removes the user count and all text which follows it.
- `s/min/minutes/`

  This replaces `min` with `minutes`.
- `s/([[:digit:]]+):0?([[:digit:]]+)/\1 hours, \2 minutes/'`

  If the line contains a time in the hh:mm format, this separates the hours from the minutes and replaces it with `hh hours, mm minutes`.

### Handling computers with short uptimes using awk

```
uptime | awk -F'( |,|:)+' '{d=h=m=0; if ($7=="min") m=$6; else {if ($7~/^day/) {d=$6;h=$8;m=$9} else {h=$6;m=$7}}} {print d+0,"days,",h+0,"hours,",m+0,"minutes."}'
```

On the same test cases as above, this produces:

```
0 days, 0 hours, 1 minutes.
0 days, 0 hours, 59 minutes.
0 days, 2 hours, 1 minutes.
1 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes.
1 days, 1 hours, 0 minutes.
25 days, 21 hours, 30 minutes.
```

For those who prefer awk code spread out over multiple lines:

```
uptime | awk -F'( |,|:)+' '{
    d=h=m=0;
    if ($7=="min")
        m=$6;
    else {
        if ($7~/^day/) { d=$6; h=$8; m=$9}
        else {h=$6;m=$7}
        }
    }
    {
        print d+0,"days,",h+0,"hours,",m+0,"minutes."
    }'
```

Comment: Thanks for the awk solution. One small improvement when piping a file with several uptimes into it, I needed to reset the variables:
`cat filewithuptimes.log | awk -F'( |,|:)+' 'd=0; h=0; m=0; {if ($7=="min") m=$6; else {if ($7~/^day/) {d=$6;h=$8;m=$9} else {h=$6;m=$7}}} {print d+0,"days,",h+0,"hours,",m+0,"minutes."}'`

Comment: @mrvulcan Good observation!  I just updated the answer to initialize those variables so that the case of multiple input lines is handled.  Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

Just vor completeness... what's about:

```
$ uptime -p
up 2 weeks, 3 days, 14 hours, 27 minutes
```

Comment: Should be an accepted answer. Works for me on ubuntu, but doesn't work for OSX.

Comment: This is great for ubuntu but does not work on redhat. For that @John answer is great.

Comment: @Eden Maybe this was true back in 2018, but right now "uptime --pretty" works on RHEL 7 and RHEL 8.

Answer (score 8):

**Solution**: In order to get the linux uptime in seconds, Go to bash and type `cat /proc/uptime`.Parse the first number and convert it according to your requirement.

From RedHat [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-proc-topfiles#s2-proc-uptime):

> This file contains **information detailing how long the system has been on since its last restart**. The output of `/proc/uptime` is quite minimal:
>
> ```
> 350735.47 234388.90
> ```
>
> The **First** number is the total number of seconds the system has been
> up.
>
> The **Second** number is how much of that time the machine has spent
> idle, in
> seconds.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is Linux specific-- it won't work on other POSIX operating systems (unless they're designed to mimic Linux)

Comment: What is the Operating System that is POSIX, but not Linux, that you have in mind?

Comment: macOS is one such operating system. @R.W.Prado

Answer (score 4):

I made a universal shell script, for systems which support `uptime -p` like newer linux and for those that don't, like Mac OS X.

```
#!/bin/sh

uptime -p >/dev/null 2>&1

if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
  # Supports most Linux distro
  # when the machine is up for less than '0' minutes then
  # 'uptime -p' returns ONLY 'up', so we need to set a default value
  UP_SET_OR_EMPTY=$(uptime -p | awk -F 'up ' '{print $2}')
  UP=${UP_SET_OR_EMPTY:-'less than a minute'}
else
  # Supports Mac OS X, Debian 7, etc
  UP=$(uptime | sed -E 's/^[^,]*up *//; s/mins/minutes/; s/hrs?/hours/;
  s/([[:digit:]]+):0?([[:digit:]]+)/\1 hours, \2 minutes/;
  s/^1 hours/1 hour/; s/ 1 hours/ 1 hour/;
  s/min,/minutes,/; s/ 0 minutes,/ less than a minute,/; s/ 1 minutes/ 1 minute/;
  s/  / /; s/, *[[:digit:]]* users?.*//')
fi

echo "up $UP"
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/ioagel/7f72863b40ed3d7c3b1d60a4d1a081c1)

Referenced John1024 answer with my own customizations.

Comment: Perfect for what I needed, and +1 for proper singular-value formatting :)

Answer (score 2):

For this:

- 0 days, 0 hours, 1 minutes.
- 0 days, 0 hours, 59 minutes.
- 0 days, 2 hours, 1 minutes.
- 1 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes.
- 1 days, 1 hours, 0 minutes.
- 25 days, 21 hours, 30 minutes

More simple is:
`uptime -p | cut -d " " -f2-`

Comment: this doesn’t print anything like “0 days”, at least not with uptime from procps-ng 3.3.16.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of variety, here's an example with sed:

My raw output:

```
$ uptime
15:44:56 up 3 days, 22:58,  7 users,  load average: 0.48, 0.40, 0.31
```

Converted output:

```
$uptime|sed 's/.*\([0-9]\+ days\), \([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\).*/\1, \2 hours, \3 minutes./'
3 days, 22 hours, 58 minutes.
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is pretty specific for the `uptime` shipped in OS X, but takes into account any case of output.

```
#!/bin/bash

INFO=`uptime`
echo $INFO | awk -F'[ ,:\t\n]+' '{
        msg = "↑ "
        if ($5 == "day" || $5 == "days") {      # up for a day or more
            msg = msg $4 " " $5 ", "

            n = $6
            o = $7
        } else {
            n = $4
            o = $5
        }

        if (int(o) == 0) {                      # words evaluate to zero
            msg = msg int(n)" "o
        } else {                                # hh:mm format
            msg = msg int(n)" hr"
            if (n > 1) { msg = msg "s" }

            msg = msg ", " int(o) " min"
            if (o > 1) { msg = msg "s" }
        }

        print "[", msg, "]"
    }'
```

---

Some example possible outputs:

```
22:49 up 24 secs, 2 users, load averages: 8.37 2.09 0.76
[ ↑ 24 secs ]

22:50 up 1 min, 2 users, load averages: 5.59 2.39 0.95
[ ↑ 1 min ]

23:39 up 51 mins, 3 users, load averages: 2.18 1.94 1.74
[ ↑ 51 mins ]

23:54 up 1:06, 3 users, load averages: 3.67 2.57 2.07
[ ↑ 1 hr, 6 mins ]

16:20 up 120 days, 10:46, 3 users, load averages: 1.21 2.88 0.80
[ ↑ 120 days, 10 hrs, 46 mins ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uptime_minutes() {
  set `uptime -p`
  local minutes=0

  shift
  while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    case $2 in
      day*)
        ((minutes+=$1*1440))
        ;;
      hour*)
        ((minutes+=$1*60))
        ;;
      minute*)
        ((minutes+=$1))
        ;;
    esac
   shift
   shift
  done

  echo $minutes
}
```